# How to add filters to OpenCover tool to skip some of the functions in classes?

Tags: code-coverage, opencover

I am able to add filters to OpenCover for skipping the classes in open cover. I want to know, How to add filters to OpenCover tool to skip some of the functions in classes?

For Example something like below(but it is not working)

```
-[*AProjectManagement*]A.VsIde.AStudio.Project.Management.AProjectNode.AddFile
```

Where,

AProjectNode is class name and AddFile is a function.

Main reason for asking this, I am using the third party SDK Inferfaces and I have to implement all of them even though I am not using it in client code. I want to avoid coverage for those function.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No filters available at this point in time, you could use a custom attribute and then use the `-excludebyattribute` feature.